# custom camera in android

Tags: android, camera

In my application I need to use custom camera. There are two buttons on the screen "Keep Image" and "Retake Photo". The picture taken by the cam should be saved in the specified directory when I click on the "keep image" button. When I click on "retake photo" button the cam should be ready to take a new photo. I have searched for the same and I got a Stack overflow link and I tried to implement that in my app, but the problem is all the code for taking picture and saving picture is written in the same class. The picture taken will be automatically saved without even a button click. I want to change that. I have tried different ways but throwing errors.

Please help me...given below is my java code

```
public class CustomCameraDemo extends Activity {

private SurfaceView preview=null;   
private SurfaceHolder previewHolder=null;   
public Camera camera=null;    
private boolean inPreview=false;   
//ImageView image;   
Bitmap bmp,itembmp;  
static Bitmap mutableBitmap;   
PointF start = new PointF();   
PointF mid = new PointF();   
float oldDist = 1f;   
File imageFileName = null;   
File imageFileFolder = null;   
private MediaScannerConnection msConn;  
Display d;   int screenhgt,screenwdh;       
ProgressDialog dialog;
Button save;
Button retake;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
   // image=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);  

    save=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Save);
    retake=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Retake);
    preview=(SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.surface);     
    previewHolder=preview.getHolder();    
    previewHolder.addCallback(surfaceCallback);    
    previewHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS); 
    previewHolder.setFixedSize(getWindow().getWindowManager()     
            .getDefaultDisplay().getWidth(), getWindow().getWindowManager() 
            .getDefaultDisplay().getHeight()); 
    save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {



        }
    });
    retake.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


        }
    });

}

@Override   public void onResume() {  
    super.onResume();   
    camera=Camera.open(); 
    }  
@Override   public void onPause() {   
    if (inPreview) {  
        camera.stopPreview();   }   
    camera.release();   
    camera=null;   
    inPreview=false;   
    super.onPause();   
    }    

private Camera.Size getBestPreviewSize(int width, int height,Camera.Parameters parameters){   
    Camera.Size result=null;   
    for (Camera.Size size : parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes()) 
    {   
        if (size.width<=width && size.height<=height)
        {
            if (result==null) {  
                result=size;   
            }   else {  
                int resultArea=result.width*result.height; 
                int newArea=size.width*size.height;  
                if (newArea>resultArea) {   
                    result=size;   
                    }  
                }   
            }   
        }   
    return(result);   
    }    
    SurfaceHolder.Callback surfaceCallback=new SurfaceHolder.Callback(){

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {     
        try {        
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(previewHolder); 
            }   catch (Throwable t) {   
                Log.e("PreviewDemo-surfaceCallback",
                        "Exception in setPreviewDisplay()", t);
                Toast.makeText(CustomCameraDemo.this, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();       
                }     
            }      
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder,int format, int width,int height) {
        Camera.Parameters parameters=camera.getParameters();       
        Camera.Size size=getBestPreviewSize(width, height,                                           
                parameters);       
        if (size!=null) {      
            parameters.setPreviewSize(size.width, size.height);
            camera.setParameters(parameters);       
            camera.startPreview();       
            inPreview=true;       
            }     
        }      
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

        }   
    };         

   Camera.PictureCallback photoCallback=new Camera.PictureCallback(){       

    public void onPictureTaken(final byte[] data, final Camera camera){      
                dialog=ProgressDialog.show(CustomCameraDemo.this,"","Saving Photo");       
                new Thread(){       
                    public void run(){       
                        try{      
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                            }       
                        catch(Exception ex){}       
                        onPictureTake(data,camera);
                        }       
                    }.start();             
                    }       
            };          
    public void onPictureTake(byte[] data, Camera camera){        
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);       
                mutableBitmap = bmp.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);       
                savePhoto(mutableBitmap);       
                dialog.dismiss();       
                }          
    class SavePhotoTask extends AsyncTask<byte[], String, String> {
                @Override       
                protected String doInBackground(byte[]... jpeg) {
                    File photo=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"photo.jpg");
                    if (photo.exists()){
                        photo.delete();
                        }       try {      
                            FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(photo.getPath()); 
                            fos.write(jpeg[0]);       
                            fos.close();       
                            } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
                                Log.e("PictureDemo", "Exception in photoCallback", e);
                                }      
                            return(null);
                                }       
                }  
    public void savePhoto(Bitmap bmp) {
                imageFileFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"MyMedicalRecords");
                imageFileFolder.mkdir();
                FileOutputStream out = null; 
                Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                String date = fromInt(c.get(Calendar.MONTH))+ fromInt(c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))
                + fromInt(c.get(Calendar.YEAR))             
                + fromInt(c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY))            
                + fromInt(c.get(Calendar.MINUTE))           
                + fromInt(c.get(Calendar.SECOND)); 
                imageFileName = new File(imageFileFolder, date.toString() + ".jpg");
                try {  out = new FileOutputStream(imageFileName);  
                bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);  
                out.flush();  out.close();  
                scanPhoto(imageFileName.toString());  
                out = null; 
                } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); } 
                }  
    public String fromInt(int val) {
                    return String.valueOf(val);
                    } 
    public void scanPhoto(final String imageFileName) {
                    msConn = new MediaScannerConnection(CustomCameraDemo.this,new MediaScannerConnectionClient() {
    public void onMediaScannerConnected() {
                            msConn.scanFile(imageFileName, null); 
                            Log.i("msClient obj  in Photo Utility","connection established"); 
                            } 
    public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                                msConn.disconnect(); Log.i("msClient obj in Photo Utility","scan completed"); 
                                }
                            }); 
                    msConn.connect(); 
                    } 
                @Override 
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event){ if ( 
                        keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU&& event.getRepeatCount() == 0) 
                { 
                    onBack(); 
                    } 
                return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event); 
                }  
    public void onBack(){ Log.e("onBack :","yes"); 
                camera.takePicture(null,null,photoCallback); 
                inPreview=false; 
    } 


}
```

given below is my main layout

```
  <RelativeLayout   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"   
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"   
 android:layout_height="fill_parent">   
 <android.view.SurfaceView   
 android:id="@+id/surface"  
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"  
  />

 <Button android:layout_width="150dip" 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
 android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
 android:text="Keep Photo" 
 android:id="@+id/Save"></Button>
 <TextView android:layout_below="@+id/surface" 
 android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
 android:id="@+id/textView1"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:text="" 
  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"></TextView>
<Button android:layout_width="150dip" 
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
  android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
 android:text="Retake Photo" 
 android:id="@+id/Retake"></Button>  </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: i am not getting correct answers.then how can i accept that? :(

Comment: Try this link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8543244/custom-camera-android/8543376#8543376

Comment: i implemented the same in my app...but i cant do the saving task in button click..that is my problem

Comment: click the Menu button to take picture and dont forget to add permissions in Manifest file.

Comment: on which button click you are performing saving task

Comment: now not doing the saving task in button click..it is automatically saving the picture once it is taken.

Comment: everything is working fine..i can take picture and it is saving to the SD card.but the problem is now it is saving once the picture is taken.but iwant to save it only when i click the "keep image" button

Comment: nobody have answer for me? :(

Comment: that is not possible...i tried that..it is throwing error

Comment: Have you implemented the custom camera without issues?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build over the existing code, you can just delete the saved image when the user opts to retake another image.