# Android: How to record video from required portion of the screen?

Tags: android, android-camera, surfaceview, video-capture

i need to capture video from required portion of the screen like -

[image]

I have tried

```
...
try {
        camera.unlock();
        recorder.setCamera(camera);
        recorder.setOrientationHint(cameraRotationDegree);
        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
        recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
        **recorder.setVideoSize(sz.width, sz.height);**
        recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);
        recorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.MPEG_4_SP);
        recorder.setOutputFile(fileName);
        recorder.prepare();
        recorder.start();
        isRecording = true;
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

but it records while screen.

is it possible to capture video from required portion of the screen?

Comment: no. not snapshot. record video from required portion of the screen

Comment: ok look at this tutorial it may help you because you already getting camera whole screen now to appear only for perticular area follow[-this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12720774/how-to-make-camera-appear-in-particular-screen-area-in-android)

Comment: Just to be clear... do you want to present the full camera preview in the upper part of the screen, and record the full frame? Show a cut-off camera preview and record the full frame? Show a cut-off camera preview and only record the visible part?

Comment: @fadden  i want to show cut - off camera preview and record only that visible part.

Comment: @Mansi Have you found any solution for this? It'd be great help :)

Comment: @Nisarg: no. as per my R & D its not possible in android. Android always records full screen video.

Comment: @Mansi Okay Thanks and For *DF* we've been searching since 20 days :(

Comment: @Nisarg: if you want to crop video it's possible from server side

Comment: @Mansi Yes but there are lots of things we have to apply on video after its being captured like trimming, filter effects etc. So for this scenario its not possible from server side i guess.

Answer (score 0):

The video is being cut off on the display by being obscured by static content.  You can't record from the display, and even if you could, you'd just end up with the static content in the video as well.

One approach is to direct the video to a SurfaceTexture, which converts each incoming frame to an OpenGL ES "external" texture.  You would then render the desired portion of the frame twice, once to the display, once to a video encoder.  This is fairly involved, but you can find examples of the various bits in [Grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika).

A less efficient but perhaps more straightforward approach would be to post-process the video file with something like [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/).  I haven't worked with it, but it seems fairly sophisticated, and may provide an easy way to re-encode a video with cropping.

The simplest option is to simply fit the camera preview into your layout, and work with the full frame.

Comment: It's possible to call **MediaCodec** from `onPreviewFrame()`, isn't it?

Comment: It's possible. I usually ignore it as an option because the frame rate will be low -- in addition to the usual overhead associated with working with `byte[]`, you have to do a color conversion on each frame, because MediaCodec's YUV inputs aren't the same as Camera's outputs (need to swap U and V). If that's not a concern, though, you could do a software copy of the relevant parts of each frame and feed them to MediaCodec on an API 18+ device.

Comment: Still much faster than software-only x264, and without the involved licensing concerns.

Comment: @AlexCohn: With ffmpeg post-processing, you can capture at full speed and do the processing offline. With `onPreviewFrame()` you're doing the extra work "inline" and will be unable to keep up with the preview. The latter is certainly a viable option when a lower frame rate is acceptable. The SurfaceTexture-based approach is the best all around, but it does require a visit to the deep end of Android.

Comment: If you can do conversions offline, MediaRecorder is just OK. Regarding YUV formats, note that ffmpeg does not support NV21 out-of-the-box, too.