# Place images on top of a Camera Preview

Tags: java, android, android-camera, surfaceview

I am new to Android Development.

I am making a children's game that when the user clicks on a camera button, it will bring up a preview of the camera with images of some of the characters over of it. I have tried various examples but I can't seem to get anything working.

Currently I am using the following intent to open the camera:

```
public void camerabuttonClick(View view) {
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 1337);

}
```

From what I've read I cannot use this in the situation I have described. Some of the examples I have used put a SurfaceView behind some ImageViews in a relative layout, but I haven't had any luck with this.

Does anyone have any ideas? Any help much appreciated!

Comment: You have to use surfaceview for this. Use a relative layout and add surface view and your image on top of it.See coommonWares example of camera preview for this.

Answer (score 0):

Here what you need to do to achieve this

1) Create Custom camera interface, with surfaceview. [link for answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8543244/custom-camera-android?rq=1)

2) Add surfaceview and image in relative layout. here image  will overlap camera-preview.

try this, it worked for me.